# C: For loop variable as it's own stopping condition?

Tags: c, shell, loops, for-loop

I am working on building a basic shell and am trying to understand a basic for loop. I am confused because I am used to for loops stopping when a condition is false, but it seems like the following for loop has p has it's own stopping condition?

```
void spawn_job(job_t *j, bool fg) 
{
pid_t pid;
process_t *p;

    for(p = j->first_process; p; p = p->next) {
         ...
    }
 }
```

Intuition tells me that the for loop will stop once a certain progress number has been reached, but I am interested in the expression of this logic - how does this work? Aren't I resetting p after every iteration of the loop? Why wasn't it written as p = some number?

Comment: "Intuition tells me" -- as a clearly very inexperienced C programmer, you should not count on your intuitions -- this one is very much wrong.  Anything non-zero is true, so it stops when `p` is NULL. This sort of loop, iterating over a linked list, is very common in C. `p = some number` -- that would be a serious bug; hopefully your compiler would warn you about an assignment in the if condition.

Comment: @JimBalter Oh, how silly of me... Thank you!

Comment: Others have told you what's going on.  I'd just add that if I was code reviewing this I'd find it bad style-  adding an explict != NULL adds clarity with no negative side effects.  In fact IMO this should be a while loop, not a for loop-  using a for for this kind of loop is very unusual.

Comment: "using a for for this kind of loop is very unusual" -- Uh, no. I've written hundreds or even thousands of them personally. I've never written this sort of thing as a while loop, and I think it's foolish to do so (it's also dangerous, if the loop contains a `continue`). The `!= NULL` can help readability, but I usually omit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard way of traversing a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). The loop terminates when p evaluates to false. In C anything that is not 0 evaluates to true. P is a pointer to a node of a linked list, it will become false when it is NULL. You can re-write this in a more clear fashion like this:

```
process_t *p;

for(p = j->first_process; p != NULL; p = p->next) {
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(p = j->first_process; p; p = p->next) {
     ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
p = j->first_process
while(p) {
     ...
     p = p->next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, if you pass a pointer to a conditional (in an if, for or while loop) it will test if that pointer is NULL.

So these:

```
proccess_t *p;

if(p){ ... }
for(p = ...; p; ...){ ... };
```

are equivalent to these

```
if(p != NULL){ ... }
for(p = ...; p != NULL; ...){ ... };
```